# I am facing problem to solve this coding problem

Tags: string, if-statement, return

def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    # code goes here
    if (first_name, last_name):

print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))

## Should return the string "Name: Hemingway, Ernest"

print(format_name("", "Madonna"))

## Should return the string "Name: Madonna"

print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))

## Should return the string "Name: Voltaire"

print(format_name("", ""))

## Should return an empty string

Comment: I think that you should rework your question (code stype, ...)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give your question a meaningful title, let us know what programming language you want to use in the tags, and fix the formatting to structure your question better.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
     return "Name: " + first_name + ", " + last_name
```

If python is what you want

Comment: does this not return an "Name: , " string for a call of format_name("", "")?